# One and Two Tailed Independent T Test Questions

Tags: statistics, self-learning, education, statistical-inference, learning

The city council for a small town has been receiving complaints from local law 
enforcement that citizens have been extremely uncooperative when pulled over for minor 
traffic violations. To remedy the situation, the city council has decided to start an 
information campaign that expresses the benefits of complying with police during minor 
traffic stops. To maximize effectiveness and minimize cost, the city council wants to know 
if they can target the campaign at specifically men or women, or if the campaign should 
be generalized to both genders. Conduct an independent samples t-test (full hypothesis 
test) to determine if the council should target their campaign and if so, at which gender.

For this test, use a p-value of .05 to set your critical value and make sure to show all 5 
steps of the hypothesis test. As part of your conclusion, apply the results and make a 
recommendation to the city council about how they should conduct their information 
campaign.

Is this a one or two tailed test. I believe it is two. Can you have a one tailed independent t test? You are just comparing means are they the same or are they different correct. I am confused as to how I am supposed to know the gender they should target. I have a tobt of -2.32 and a tcv of +or- 2.11. If you need any of the other data please let me know. Obviously if this is a two tail then we reject the null. But I am still hung up on how I would tell which group should be targeted.

Comment: What type of data are you given? Also, ask yourself: Why would you target only one gender? Hint: I would guess it's because they complain *significantly* more than the other gender ;-)

Comment: I was given an uneven amount of cases with a score for men and women's "compliance w/ Police". I guess I am trying to figure out how I would know which gender is more compliant. Since this is a independent T test I am only comparing the men and women's means. But I cant just use the xbar because there is a different amount of cases for each, right? I can give whatever numbers you might want, if you want them.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an uneven number of cases and want to use a T-test, you should use the "pooled T-test" of the difference in the two groups, then if it is significant, you should target the group with the higher group average, since they complain more.